# Unzip file on server (Windows , plesk)

Tags: asp.net, plesk

I have a file that was uploaded to my host that has password, how can in unzip file on the server ?

I know password  !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) for zipping and unzipping files.

Comment: Good , Tested and work good for Zipped files , how about sfx files that maded in winrar ?

Comment: You would need a Rar Library for that. @Moslem7026

Comment: Okey ,rar Library can extract sfx file that encrtypted with password?